# Is range variable possible in C# (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I'm looking for some class or data type to allow me define a range for it.
This is the pseudo code which I'm looking for :

```
[Range(0, 75)] int ChildAge;
```

This range rule should be applied to any int which this Age is assigned like following

```
var MotherAge = ChildAge;
MotherAge = 100;
```

MotherAge should be set to 75 and this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: C# does not support that.

Comment: There is nothing baked in, but it is trivial to do yourself: range checks before assigning values; custom `Range<T>` type; etc.

Comment: @SLaks Is there any alternative ways to achieve this ?

Comment: Even if you fix `ChildAge` to a certain range, you can't limit the range of `MotherAge`. `MotherAge = 100` means set `MotherAge` to `100`, regardless of the valid range of `ChildAge`.

Comment: @Madhi: you could implement a simple property instead of using a field.

Comment: An AOP approach may also fill this requirement if you want to decorate properties with attributes, look into PostSharp or Castle AOP.

Comment: Why would the mother age be set to 75 if the range was on the child age? By the looks of your code you're asking to limit the range of the child, but then expect this to also affect the mother?

Comment: @PeteEbdon This is just an example

Comment: you could create a `class` `Age`, with a `min`, `max` and `value` property. Then add a method `void SetRange(Age a)` to set the equal range.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another option would be to define your own data type to represent age values. This type could enforce the constraints.

```
struct Age
{
    const int MinAge = 0;
    const int MaxAge = 75;

    readonly byte value;

    public int Value { get { return value; } }

    private Age(int value) {
        this.value = (byte) Math.Max(MinAge, Math.Min(MaxAge, value));
    }

    public static implicit operator Age(int value) {
        // Throw here if value is out of range, maybe?
        return new Age(value);
    }

    public static implicit operator int(Age age) {
        return age.value;
    }
}

    //usage:
    Age childAge = 12; // 12
    Age motherAge = 100; // 75
```

Edit: I would point out that it is generally considered bad practice to have "lossy" conversions exposed as implicit casts. I should have made the `operator int(Age)` conversion `explicit` instead. This would require writing an explicit cast `Age age = (Age) 100;` which advertises to the consumer of the API that the cast isn't "identity preserving". This is similar to a cast from `long` to `int` or `double` to `float`, there is a loss of range/precision so the language requires you be explicit about it to demonstrate that you understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 6):

There is no such thing in C#, but you could create a class that handles it easily:

```
public class Age
{
    public Age(int age) : this(0, 75, age) { }
    public Age(int minAge, int maxAge) : this(minAge, maxAge, minAge) { }
    public Age(int minAge, int maxAge, int age)
    {
        this._Minimum = minAge;
        this._Maximum = maxAge;
        this.Value = age;
    }

    private int _Value = 0;
    public int Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _Value;
        }
        set
        {
           CheckRange(value, true);
        }
    }

    private int _Maximum = 0;
    public int MaximumAge
    {
        get
        {
            return _Maximum;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value < _Minimum)
                throw new ArgumentException("MaximumAge");
            _Maximum = value;
            CheckRange(value, false);
        }
    }
    private int _Minimum = 0;
    public int MinimumAge
    {
        get
        {
            return _Minimum;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value > _Maximum)
                throw new ArgumentException("MinimumAge");
            _Minimum = value;
            CheckRange(value, false);
        }
    }

    private void CheckRange(int value, bool setValueAnyway)
    {
        if (value < _Minimum)
            _Value = _Minimum;
        else if (value > _Maximum)
            _Value = _Maximum;
        else if (setValueAnyway)
            _Value = value;
    }
}
```

Now your sample ages:

```
Age childAge = new Age(0,75);
Age motherAge = childAge;
motherAge.Value = 100;   // 75
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need an attribute. You can use a `property`:

```
private int _age;
public int ChildAge
{
   get { return _age; }
   set
   { 
      if(value > 75)
         _age = 75;
      else if(value < 0)
         _age = 0;
      else
         _age = value;

   } 
}
```

Comment: don't forget to declare _age

Comment: And how does this prevents MotherAge to be lower than 75!?

Comment: @Mahdi It doesn't. This approach would need to be on a per-property basis. Of course the code could be centralised somewhere, but it sounds like you want to define your own type to encapsulate the logic of what you want a "range" to be. We've done it, it's straightforward and works well.

Comment: @Mahdi try it and see.

Comment: @Madhi: if you need to use this repeatedly, you could refactor the logic into a function, so it reads something like `_age = LimitValue(value, 0, 75);`, and reuse `LimitValue` appropriately.

Comment: @Selman22 This doesn't prevent other integers be between 0 and 75 but only ChildAge because it's a property itself

Comment: @Mahdi you can't do it.int is not a reference type and you can't bind ChildAge value to an integer variable